# Issue with TOvcTCCheckBox provided by Orpheus control

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using Orpheus control v4.08 along with Delphi XE2 and I am facing below described issue.

I am using TOvcTable and its one of the column is TOvcTCCheckBox. This table is editable. At run time check box column can be checked or unchecked.

Now for checking this column I need to click this column twice.

This was working fine in Delphi 4 with Orpheus control version v3.08. Check box column is getting checked/unchecked in single click.

**Note: There is one property AcceptActivationClick which is set to true in both the cases mentioned above.**

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Can anyone create new tag for Orpheus Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaraound: Use OvcTable's MouseDown-Event as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.OvcTable1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
   RowNum, ColNum: Integer;
begin
   OvcTable1.CalcRowColFromXY(X, Y, RowNum, ColNum);
   if (OvcTable1.Columns.List[ColNum].DefaultCell is TOvcTCCheckBox) and
      ((RowNum <> OvcTable1.ActiveRow) or (ColNum <> OvcTable1.ActiveCol)) then
   begin
      PostMessage(OvcTable1.Handle, ctim_StartEdit, 0, 0);
      PostMessage(OvcTable1.Handle, ctim_StartEditMouse, 0, X + 65536 * Y);
   end;
end;
```

Source: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=529790&aid=3562412&group_id=71004